# How to apply a pattern rule to more than one directory?

Tags: c++, makefile

I am working on a CPP project and I have a folder with the source code (src) and another external code folder on which the first one depends.
I need to generate the files with the extension `.o` from both folders.

I have these targets working well:

```
# Generate object files from .cpp files of external source code
$(OBJECTS_PATH)%.o : $(EXTERNAL_SRC_PATH)%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXX_EXTRA_FLAGS) -c $^ -o $@

# Generate object files from .cpp files of my source code
$(OBJECTS_PATH)%.o : $(SOURCE_CODE_PATH)%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXX_EXTRA_FLAGS) -c $^ -o $@
```

Is there any way to unify the targets?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to unify the targets?

There is a way to unify the targets as long as object files are built into a directory hierarchy isomorphic to the source hierarchy. Otherwise, you may have name clashes, e.g., different source directories may have source files with the same name which all build into the same object file.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear which source file should be preferred if both exist.

The usual technique is to add both of your source directories to `VPATH`, in the desired order.

If you then change to compile to the current directory, and change `CXX_EXTRA_FLAGS` to the standard `CXXFLAGS`, then the rules could be entirely omitted, as the built-in rules would be sufficient.